# Python: script gets stuck on Keyboard.wait()

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-keyboard

So it just breaks when holding down while holding down SHIFT ALT or CTRL While the function is running, When It does break I do try tapping SHIFT ALT and CTRL to see if they are stuck down and they aren't so I'm all out of ideas.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import random

def feint():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    print('1')
    if number == 1:
        pyautogui.keyDown('LEFT')
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.keyUp('LEFT')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
        pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
    if number == 2:
        #ETC
```

The `feint2()` Is just the same code twice with already used options out of play and the attack is the same as the  `feint()` without the  `pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl') pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')`

```
import pyautogui
import random
import feinter
from attacker import attack
import keyboard

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

def feintmarco():
    number = random.randint(1,2)
    if number == 1:
        feinter.feint()
        print('0')
        attack()
    if number == 2:
        feinter.feint2()
        print('0')
        attack()
keyboard.add_hotkey('Num -', feintmarco)
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: You're not passing anything to `wait()`. From the [source code](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L991) of the `keyboard` module, you can clearly see that if nothing is passed in, the script will just loop forever with `_time.sleep(1e6)`. Notice the "`or, if given no parameters, blocks forever.`" part. You need to specify which key you are waiting for.

Comment: @RandomDavis Even when adding `keyboard.wait('=')` the code still gets stuck by the same rules as before. Even when pressing the wait key.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. And what `SHIFT ALT or CTRL` has to do with this problem. Maybe first test script only with `keyboard.wait("=")` . Maybe it has some conflict with other code which we can't see. OR maybe it has conflict with `pyautogui` which has functions to send keys to system.

Comment: @furas That's what I don't understand and it works if I don't use SHIFT ALT or CTRL at all
Both the wait and the hotkey but I need to hold shift for most Marco to be effective.
I could post the feinter and attack codes too.

Comment: if you have to keep `SHIFT ALT or CTRL` then you should use different hotkeys - with `SHIFT ALT or CTRL` - because for system `=`and `Shift+=` and `Ctrl+=`, `Ctrl+Shift+=`, `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+=`  are 5 different hotkeys.

Comment: for single key you can use `keyboard.on_press_key('=', your_function)` and it will run function when you press `=` or `Shift+=`, `Ctrl+=`, `Ctrl+Shift+=`, `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+=`, etc.

Comment: When using `keyboard.on_press_key('=', your_function)` I have to Loop it with a `while True` and it causes issues delaying the keyboard
Doing it with `keyboard.wait('=')` doesnt seem to actually work at all
Also I think most the keys on the keyboard if not all of them react differently when pressing **SHIFT ALT** or **CTRL**. If I could add mutiple hotkeys to do the same thing it wouldn't be too bad but I get bad reactions from that too.

Comment: Even when adding 
`keyboard.add_hotkey('Num -', feintmarco)
keyboard.add_hotkey('SHIFT + Num -', feintmarco)
keyboard.add_hotkey('SHIFT + Num - + W', feintmarco)`
and so forth it still gets caught up on nothing.